# Grouping logic in R

Tags: r

I am trying to get some grouping done and cannot do it

The subset of data I have is this

```
     name   value   group    num    range
     ----- -------  ------  ------  -------
      A      1        1      3      Jan2000-March2000
      A      0        2      1      Apr2000-Apr2000
      A      1        3      8      May2000-Dec2000
      A      0        4      1      Jan2001-Jan2001
      A      1        5      1      Feb2001-Feb2001
      A      0        6      9      March2001-Nov2001
      A      1        7      1      Dec2001-Dec2001
      A      0        8      1      Jan2002-Jan2002
      A      1        9      1      Feb2002-Feb2002
      A      0        10     2      March2002-April2002
```

I want to ignore the groups with value 0 and num 1 which are in between groups with value 1 and num>=1 and merge them together.

For example in the data above, I would like to ignore row 2 and 4, and combine them with groups of value 1 since these rows have value of 0 with numb =1

The condition that starts a new group is either a row with value 0 and num>1 or a row with value 1 and num>=1

The output should be as follows:

```
     name   value   group    num    range
     ----- -------  ------  ------  -------
      A      1        1      14     Jan2000-Feb2001
      A      0        2      9      Mar2001-Nov2001
      A      1        3      3      Dec2001-Feb2002
      A      0        10     2      March2002-April2002
```

This is to be done for more than 1 names like B,C,D etc

Comment: Row 4 is not between groups with `value == 1 & num > 1`. The 5th row is `value == 1 and num == 1`.

Comment: @thelatemail I made the edit. Can you help me out here?

Comment: What's the condition that starts a new group? If there are two rows in a row that *don't* have `value == 0` and `num == 1`, do they form separate groups?

Comment: Have you considered having your `range` be *actual `Date`s*? Or does it not matter and you just want *"everything before the hyphen in the first row and everything after the hyphen in the last row"*?

Comment: @Marius The condition that starts a new group is either a row with value 0 and num>1  or a row with value 1 and num>=1

Comment: @r2evans It doesn't matter. I just need everything before the hyphen when the group starts and everything after the hyphen when the group ends.

Comment: There is no logical explanation as to how you got tye expected results from your dataframe

Comment: @Onyambu I have all possible details in the post. Could you let me know what understanding do you need for me to explain?

Comment: you start from the first row, then how do you determine that the 6th row is the second? what makes you sum rows 1-5 together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have a working solution for this (although it doesn't account for different `name`s yet) - it seems like a fairly tricky problem. It's probably not a particularly efficient solution, as it finds a single row to collapse, collapses it, and then checks the whole dataset again and goes through the process until there are no more rows to collapse. If there are more efficient ways to do this, I'd like to see them:

```
# Identify which rows are "between" rows that can be collapsed
get_between_info = function(data) {
    data %>%
        mutate(outer_row = value == 1 & num >= 1,
               inner_row = value == 0 & num == 1,
               between_row = inner_row & lead(outer_row) & lag(outer_row))
}

df = df %>%
    get_between_info()

while (any(df$between_row)) {
    collapse_group = which(df$between_row)[1] + c(-1, 0, 1)
    collapsed = summarise(df[collapse_group, ], 
                          name = first(name),
                          value = 1, 
                          group = first(group), 
                          num = sum(num),
                          range = paste0(
                              str_split(range[1], "-")[[1]][1],
                              "-",
                              str_split(range[n()], "-")[[1]][2]
                           ))
    before = df %>% filter(row_number() < collapse_group[1])
    after = df %>% filter(row_number() > collapse_group[3])

    df = bind_rows(before, collapsed, after)
    df = df %>% get_between_info()
}
```

Output (I don't understand the logic for determining `group` numbers so mine differ):

```
> df
  name value group num               range outer_row inner_row between_row
1    A     1     1  14     Jan2000-Feb2001      TRUE     FALSE       FALSE
2    A     0     6   9   March2001-Nov2001     FALSE     FALSE       FALSE
3    A     1     7   3     Dec2001-Feb2002      TRUE     FALSE       FALSE
4    A     0    10   2 March2002-April2002     FALSE     FALSE       FALSE
```

The collapsing code could probably be cleaned up by first splitting the `range` column into separate `range_start` and `range_end` columns (before starting any of this process) - it would make generating the collapsed df much cleaner.

Comment: thanks. This doesn't solve the issue of running over all the names. But this one is really commendable!